# Need help horizontally centering elements which are dynamically positioned with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, css-transforms, jquery-isotope

Here is the website I'm working on: https://frankli-n.github.io/portfolio/memsmosaics/filter/filterable-gallery/dist/m_index.html#gallery

The image section is responsive - as you narrow the window you get less image columns. The problem is these columns aren't centred. I want them to always be horizontally centred inside the window. This is particularly important for the aesthetics on the mobile view.

This must have something to do with how the `<img>` tags are being positioned in the `<div id="gallery-content-center">` and it is complicated for me because the `<img>` tags have dynamically changing positioning with the transform property which allows them to jump columns when they are cut off.

```
style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 258px, 0px);
```

Here's a screenshot of the window at a width where the images are clearly not centered and the img tag (for the red top right picture) transform positioning is highlighted in the inspect.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to use margin: 0 auto; on your gallery?

Comment: Yes I did. The problem is that the white space to the right of the images is considered part of the #gallery-content div, so the div technically is centered. I need some way for it to just see the images when centering.

Comment: Since you are using fixed width for your items, if you calculate and give fixed width to your container with media queries, that should work. For example suppose you have 2 items each having  50px width in a row with 15px spacing, the container should be 115px wide. Also don’t forget margin auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you should do considering your case:

```
#gallery-content-center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1240px;
    float: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
    #gallery-content-center {
        width: 930px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    #gallery-content-center {
        width: 620px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
    #gallery-content-center {
        width: 310px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved it perfectly. Thank you so much this has been with me for days.